# NullReferenceException when adding to ArrayList

Tags: vb.net, arraylist, nullreferenceexception

I am attempting to add to an ArrayList using the following.

```
Dim lines() As String = IO.File.ReadAllLines("C:\xTools\messages.txt")
For Each line As String In lines
  Dim parts As String() = line.Split(New String() {":"}, StringSplitOptions.None)
  Dim message As String = String.Join(" ", parts)
  If Not message = Nothing Then
    Messages.Add(message)
  End If
Next
```

All I get is NullReferenceExceptions on `Messages.Add(message)`. Please advise.

Comment: What is the definition of the variable `Messages`?

Comment: I'd also try to avoid using an ArrayList. Try using collections from the `System.Collections.Generic` namespace, eg `List(Of T)` ...

Comment: @Styxxy: ...List(Of String) in this case...

Comment: @Neolisk In this case, yes ;-).

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you get `NullReferenceException` in a particular line, examine the line with respect to your code flow, i.e. you generally should know which of the variables or expressions can get a value of `Nothing`, so start with those first. Use either mouse hover or your immediate window.

In your example, message cannot be `Nothing`, because it's been checked previously for that. Also please do consider changing it to `Is Nothing`, rather than `= Nothing`. As written, it will also react to `String.Empty`, which is misleading. If you really want this behavior, use [`String.IsNullOrEmpty`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorempty.aspx).

So the only thing that can be `Nothing` is `Messages`, which was probably never initialized:

```
Messages = New ArrayList
```

Or inline with declaration:

```
Dim Messages As New ArrayList
```

If you know that your `Messages` will always contain a list of strings, consider changing to [`Generic.List(Of String)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx), you should get what you have now + type safety. You are only stuck with `ArrayList` class if using framework 1.1, and frankly by now all your projects should be at least 2.0, so consider upgrading if you haven't done so yet.

Answer (score 0):

You get `NullReferenceExceptions` because `Messages` is in fact `null`.

Make sure that `Messages` is initialized with something, e.g. a new instance of `ArrayList`.